# Two different object instance printing same result of first instance

Tags: python-3.x, python-class, python-object

I have the following code:

```
from iqoptionapi.stable_api import IQ_Option

def fun(mail, password):
    acc = IQ_Option(mail, password)
    acc.connect()
    return acc.get_balance()
    acc.api.close()

account_one_balance = fun("testioption837@gmail.com", "Pituo67")
account_two_balance = fun("shaggggycaba@gmail.com", "1q2we4r5t6y7u8i9o0p")

print(account_one_balance, account_two_balance)
```

Account One Balance is 10036
Account Two Balance is 10000

But what is prints is:

```
10036
10036
```

I am not able to figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Anything after the `return` line in a function will not be run, which means your API connection is not being closed.

The behavior in this case will depend on how the API is designed, but most likely the second connection is simply not being opened, and the first one is maintained. That is why you get the balance from the first function twice.

Try doing this instead:

```
acc.connect()
balance = acc.get_balance()
acc.api.close()
return balance
```